# Get the second line of a Text File in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

My text file looks like this

```
Fruit 
Vegetable
```

And I need the function to return `Vegetable`

This is the code I tried to use and get "Vegetable":

```
String getItem()
{
ifstream stream("data.txt");

stream.ignore ( 1, '\n' );

std::string line;
std::getline(stream,line);

std::string word;
return word.c_str();
}
```

Then I did this to try and put the second line into an edit box:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    Edit1->Text = getItem();
}
```

For some reason, when I run the code the Edit Box eventually just has nothing in it, completely blank.

Comment: `getItem()` returns an empty string. `word` is never populated with any content. Everything above `std::string word;` line is an elaborate no-op.

Comment: The `ignore` call only searches the next 1 characters, which is not enough.  I don't know why you don't just call `getline` twice and be done with it.

Comment: ifstream stream("data.txt");

 std::string line;

 std::getline(stream,line);
 std::getline(stream,line);

 return line.c_str();

Like that? That returns the first line

Comment: What?  Yes, but no: the second call will overwrite the string with the second line of input, assuming it succeeded.  What is the datatype `String`?  Is this something you defined yourself, such as `typedef char* String;`?  If so, then your program has undefined behavior and it can never work like that.  Do not return pointers to memory that has been destroyed.  Also, don't hide basic types like pointers in your own made-up typedefs.  This makes your code less readable, and more prone to bugs.

Comment: @paddy [`String`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.String) is an alias for C++Builder's default RTL string type, which is [`System::UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) in C++Builder 2009 and later, and is [`System::AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString) in C++Builder 2007 and earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st parameter of `istream::ignore()` is expressed in *characters*, not *lines*.  So, when you call `stream.ignore(1, '\n')`, you are ignoring only **1 character** (ie, the `F` of `Fruit`), not **1 line**.

To ignore a whole line, you need to pass in `std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` instead of `1`.  That tells `ignore()` to ignore all characters until the specified terminator (`'\n'`) is encountered.

Also, you are `return`'ing a blank `String`.  You are ignoring the `line` that you read with `std::getline()`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

String getItem()
{
    std::ifstream stream("data.txt");

    //stream.ignore(1, '\n');
    stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::string line;
    std::getline(stream, line);

    return line.c_str();
    // or: return String(line.c_str(), line.size());
}
```